# MYSQL Database Query not giving back expected results

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a database which has the configuration as shown in the picture
[image: Config of Database Table]

I am trying to query

`SELECT * FROM emails WHERE ('from_type=Manager' OR 'to_type=Manager') AND ('from=2' OR 'to=2')`

It is giving me back a blank result, even though I think it should give me the one query I have set,

[image]

Comment: do you need one record only

Comment: The way you've written it, I would expect it to return all the records, not a blank result.

Comment: ohhh you already given answer @Barmer..good

Comment: @KamleshGupta No, I don't, but right now I only have one record

Comment: so actually, what you really want? can you please describe more..we get it better

Comment: I wanted to view all records matching the query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Explanation:** It will select all the values from emails table WHERE the (from_type/to_type) belongs to Manager AND (from/to) belongs to 2. Hence the condition will be based on True AND True condition alone. otherwise it will not work

```
SELECT * FROM emails 
WHERE (`from_type`= 'Manager' OR `to_type`='Manager') AND (`from`='2' OR `to`='2')
```

Instead of adding a double quotes around the whole expressing, use ` and '

For an example,

```
`from_type`= 'Manager'
```

instead of

```
'from_type=Manager'
```

Comment: Why should he try this code? Your answer should explain what's wrong and how you've fixed it, not just provide code. This is supposed to be an educational site, not a code snippet repository.

Comment: Here is the Explanation about the code: It will select all the values from emails table WHERE the (from_type/to_type) belongs to Manager AND (from/to) belongs to 2. Hence the condition will be based on True AND True condition alone. otherwise it will not work.

Comment: Have provided the explanation for my answer @Tim Malone.

Comment: @TimMalone Edited the Question with Explanation. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Don't quote your comparison expressions, just quote the string values that you're comparing with.

Also, since `from` and `to` are MySQL [reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html) you need to escape them with backticks.

```
SELECT * 
FROM emails 
WHERE (from_type='Manager' OR to_type='Manager') AND (`from`='2' OR `to`='2')
```

Comment: Hi, Naresh Kumar's answer worked! The only problem in your query was that from, and to are part of MYSQL words, which is why it picks them as something like DESC or WHERE etc.. But thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You need to loose the `'` from identifiers:

```
WHERE (from_type='Manager' OR to_type='Manager') AND (from='2' OR to='2')
```

Comment: You are right, but as I commented in another answer, it picks up the "to" and "from', But thanks for trying to help